# Formatting PHP Date to javascript still fails

Tags: javascript, php, date

I'm getting the server time in the expected format with the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Honolulu");
$date = date("D M d Y H:i:s O");
```

And in the PHP file, I'm passing it as window variable to javascript:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.jsDate = '". $date ."';</script>";
```

The js is logging it as expected:

```
var rightNow = window.jsDate;
console.log("right now: " + rightNow);
Result: right now: "Fri May 08 2015 17:13:36 -1000"
```

However, when I try to use it as a date `var date1 = new Date(rightNow.getFullYear(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);`, I'm still getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: rightNow.getFullYear is not a function
```

Even though they print the same, maybe it's not in the right format? What can I do to make this work?

Note: I don't get the error if I use `var rightNow = new Date();` instead of pulling the window variable.

Comment: `window.jsDate` looks invalid... Maybe you mean `window.Date()` or just `Date()`?

Comment: Sorry, that comes from here: echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.jsDate = '". $date ."';</script>";

Comment: $date is from here: $date = date("D M d Y H:i:s O");

Comment: Please add that to your post for context.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because `$date = date("D M d Y H:i:s O");` does not create a **JavaScript** date object. It creates a **PHP Date** (which you are converting to a string using `'`s). You need to wrap that inside of a JS `Date` constructor like so:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.jsDate = new Date('". $date ."');</script>";
```

Then `window.jsDate` will be a JS Date object and you can use the `getFullYear()` function on `rightNow`.

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but what I've tried already is wrapping it inside a js date construct in the js file. Naming the var like this: var rightNow = new Date( window.jsDate ); I got the same result.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, though, hold on.

Comment: I no longer get the error, but I'm getting the timezone back as GMT-7, which is what I get when I just use new Date(); in JS, as opposed to GMT-10, which is what I'm setting it as in php...kind of defeating the purpose. Am I going to be able to get around using the user's computer's time?

Comment: Ugh, dates... I am dealing with the same problem in one of my applications as well. You might want to look into [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

Comment: It sort of just looks like new Date( $date ); is the same new Date();